# How to send 50% of application traffic to the existing journey whilst sending 50% through a new code in React (Running on Node)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-applications

I am working on a web application and it has been developing using React and running on Node 16.8.0.

I have use-case that sends 50% of application traffic to the existing journey whilst sending 50% through a new code.

I have an idea of using any variable (Boolean) on the server side and using that to conditionally render the application subsequently and update that variable after every request.

Answer (score 0):

Netlify got a feature called [split testing](https://docs.netlify.com/site-deploys/split-testing/), maybe it could suit your needs and its quick to get started